# htaccess rewrite subdomain without filename map and extension

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Is there a way of doing a rewrite JUST for a subdomain? So it needs to affect only the subdomain. I'm looking for a way to 'hide' the maps/filename+extension.

Example:

```
www.sub.domain.com/mapname/filename.php#settings
```

simply to

```
www.sub.domain.com
```

This has to be done for every single file in the subdomain directory. I have no clue how to do this. I'm not familiar with .htaccess and I cant really find anything useful.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition so that a rule is only affected by a subdomain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
```

right above your rule.

However, not sure if there's any way to "hide" the `/mapname/filename.php#settings` part of the URL. If that part of the URL is never sent to the webserver, the webserver isn't going to know what to serve. What you may want to look into is running your entire site in an iframe, so that only `www.sub.domain.com` shows in the browser's URL address bar.